# How to solve race condition of writing to database in a distributed system

Tags: database, race-condition, distributed-system

Let's say I have a service that allows employees to create an expense report. This service writes each expense report as a row in some database. There can be multiple instances of this service running at any given time

Each time an employee tries to create a new expense report, the service checks how many entries already exist for the employee by reading from the DB. If they already have N or more active reports, the employee's request is rejected

There is a race condition when the employee submits multiple expense reports rapidly, which could be processed in parallel by different instances of the service

We can end up with the following sequence of events, assuming our limit is 5 expense reports per employee

1. Expense A requested
2. Expense B requested
3. Service instance 1 receives request A
4. Service instance 2 receives request B
5. Service instance 1 reads from DB and finds 4 entries for employee
6. Service instance 2 reads from DB and finds 4 entries for employee
7. Service instance 1 writes A to DB
8. Service instance 2 writes B to DB

Now there are 6 entries for the employee which violates the limit. What are some options for solving such race conditions in distributed systems?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some kind of lock in the system to make sure operations don't miss each other updates.

First option is to decide on a level of lock. For example, the system could allow only single update happening at the same time (read and write). Or the system could put a lock on a specific employee id.

Since you already have a database, and all services read from the same database, it seems the database is the rendezvous point, this is where all requests meet.

From practical standpoint, the database probably has some transactional support. The service (an instance of the service) would lock specific employee id for update to make sure no more than one process may insert new values. Basically read-check-update sequence won't run in parallel.

If the database does not support transactions, an external lock management service may be used.